# Is it important to backup public keys for iOS Developer Certificates?

Tags: ios, keychain, certificate

I have read everywhere that you need to backup your **private keys** for iOS Developer Certificates on your Mac. I want to know if **public key** is important to backup or not. In case if a person just keeps backup of Private keys of all certificates, can public keys be recovered on new OS installation using those old private keys? Or in other words, can I re-use those old backup certificates successfully? So Does it really matter if I do not backup public keys?

May be it's a lame Question, but I want to know about it. Thanks for helping me out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need of backing up the **Public Key** as it is **in** the actual *Certificate*, which can be easily downloaded from the **[iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action)**.

When you manually generate a *Certificate*, you firstly need to generate a *Certificate Signing Request* through the **Keychain Access** application. When this is done, both **Public** and **Private** keys are generated. The private one is automatically saved into your Mac, whilst the public key is included in the **CSR** file sent to the *Provisioning Authority*. One of the items contained **in** the generated certificate sent back from the *Provisioning Authority* will be this public key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does matter. You can backup if you want to, but I would say it's important.

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/90538-critical-back-up-your-developer-key.html

Comment: Thank you but I have already visited this link. It tells about private key backup, not public key.