# Sharing a provisioning profile among team members under a non-company subscription

Tags: developer-program, certificate

Let's say there are two iOS developers using 4 computers in total, working on the same project. Because code signing information in the Xcode project file gets checked in to the source repo, and because they can't share the same provisioning profile, it becomes a headache for obvious reasons.

I know it's possible to use your own certs and prov. profiles on multiple computers, but is there a way to share at least the prov. profile (for development) between individuals without a company subscription?

Thanks.

Comment: For just development you don't need a profile at all. Only if you'd like to test on a real device or send out a beta version or launch the "real" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provisioning Profiles **can** be shared without problems between developers. For them to be valid and usable, though, having both **Public** and **Private** keys is needed.

The **Public** key is stored *[in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117301/21487)* the **Certificate** whilst the **Private** has to be exported from the certificate's creator **Keychain App**.

Comment: OK but a cert is always a personal thing, so if I give away my cert to someone else, they can e.g. use to to sign god knows what on my name? Not that I'm expecting my partners to do it, but to understand the procedure.

Comment: @mojuba Yes. Certificates are used as a security measure to ensure the App's integrity.