# How to share a provisioning profile between 2 developers and use it to distribute an app?

Tags: ios, developer-program

As a developer I want to know can I use a provisioning profile generated by another developer who has a paid apple developer account to distribute an ios react native app build with expo?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/119686

Comment: @Thinkr Thanks. But I can't figure out how to use it with expo eas services. This is my first expo ios app. It will be great if you can explain how to use the provisioning profile with eas.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I have no clue. I am not using these services, but there's surely going to be someone here that does. :)

Comment: @Thinkr Thanks. I'm looking for help from someone.